# simple login system in php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i have a website designed with php-html-mysql. There is a user login system. User type is 3.

1. Admin
2. User
3. Visitors

this 3 type of user has different type of access in pages. MENU items are different. say, Admin can edit,delete,update some information but free user cannot.

i had created the pages. but how can i differ the access in every page? i mean, i have to load menu in every page. but for admin, menu items will be different, rather then users, and also differs to the visitors.

I am trying to use SESSION, but not sure how to use this. and how i can apply for my scenario.

Comment: Do you have access to a database to store user data? (for example a MYSQL database is very common for this sort of thing)

Comment: How about checking few existing questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265336/creating-user-roles

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes. i have a mysql database and login is managed by the db. after login, how could i remember that who is the user(ADMIN/User/Visitor)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user in what ever page. So if you have an **edit.php** script, check it at the top:

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] != 'admin') {
    die('You do not have permission to view this page.');
}

// continue showing edit form
```

I don't know the set-up of your session structure or database structure where you're storing users because you didn't provide them, so this is the best I—or any one—can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create in your database in users table the "user_level" OR another field,with 0 or 1 possible values ... If level of user is 0 then user is simple user, else if is 1 then user is admin.
 And on user login, save the session 'user_level' from 'user_level' field.

Then on every page check:

```
<?
if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) { display_menu_for_admin(); }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create access levels.
Firstly, please create separate files for handling sessions, menus.
Create a class that will determine the access to a file.
On every page, call this class function and you are done with access levels.

For example, create a file for handling menu items.
If they are totally different, depending upon the access levels, switch between the files.
Also, if the there is slight change in the menu, just add if else condition.
This way, you will get easier menu systems.
Apply this for other site functionality. e.g. Mange site variables etc. For which access is only given to admin users.